# Mapbox iOS8 Swift mapView.showUsersLocation

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, mapbox

Im trying using Mapbox iOS8 Swift cocoa plugin for mapbox and facing an issue when trying to show the users location on a mapView. My code is the following

```
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView!, symbolNameForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation!) -> String! {
    return "secondary_marker"
}

let manager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, accessToken: "pk.privateMapboxAccessTokenGoesHere")
    mapView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true

   let x:MGLUserLocation = mapView.userLocation
   println(mapView.userLocation)
   println(x.coordinate.latitude)
   println(x.coordinate.longitude)

   ... more code here to show map works.

}
```

I've made the necessary changes to info.pList and get the appropriate message the first time i fire up my app. The issue is, it prints the following:

```
<MGLUserLocation: 0x7fd8aa6c9a00>
3.40282346638529e+38
3.40282346638529e+38
```

Can anyone provide me an example of how I can show the users location (blue dot) on the map.

Answer (score 1):

To have the map automatically center on the user's location, set `mapView.userTrackingMode = .Follow` ([`MGLUserTrackingModeFollow`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.0.1/Constants/MGLUserTrackingMode.html) in Objective C).

To merely show the user's location (but not move to it), set [`mapView.showsUserLocation = true`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.0.1/Classes/MGLMapView.html#//api/name/showsUserLocation).

The reason why you're seeing bogus numbers for `mapView.userLocation` is that the user's location typically isn't available yet in `viewDidLoad`. Use the [`mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.0.1/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#//api/name/mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:) delegate method to be notified when the user's location becomes available and when it updates.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for giving me a starting point.

I used your code and added the userLocation to my map and it is showing up for me.

```
    if let userLocation = mapView.userLocation {
        userLocation.title = "USER LOCATION MARKER"
        mapView.addAnnotation(userLocation)
    }
```

Note that I had to plug in my iPhone and run it from there.  Don't know if it's supposed to work in the simulator.