# How should I find the correct location data using userLocation in Mapbox for iOS SDK? (Swift)

Tags: ios, mapbox, userlocation

I'm trying to find the latitude and longitude of the user's location so that I can center the map on the user in viewdidload.

I've implemented what seems to be the right code but the values of userLat (latitude) and userLon (longitude) are way off.

N.B. Somebody else had the same problem as me but his answer was never resolved:
[Mapbox iOS8 Swift mapView.showUsersLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914419/mapbox-ios8-swift-mapview-showuserslocation)

```
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

//    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MGLMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Initalise map's center coordinate as vancouver
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 49.283382,
            longitude: -123.117394),
            zoomLevel: 15, animated: false)
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        // Set the delegate property of our map view to self after instantiating it.
        mapView.delegate = self

        // User location
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        let userLoc = mapView.userLocation!
        userLoc.title = "Hello"
        userLoc.subtitle = "I am here!"

        let userLat = userLoc.coordinate.latitude
        let userLon = userLoc.coordinate.longitude

        print(userLat, userLon)

        /*
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }*/

    }

    func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Resulting print:

```
3.40282346638529e+38 3.40282346638529e+38
```

The strange thing is that the annotation works fine, and when I click my location I get the title and subtitle.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way to center the map on the user's location is to set `MGLMapView.userTrackingMode = .follow` ([`MGLUserTrackingModeFollow`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.5.0/Enums/MGLUserTrackingMode.html#/c:@E@MGLUserTrackingMode@MGLUserTrackingModeFollow) in Objective C). This will automatically move the map when a location is available.

The reason why you're seeing bogus numbers for `MGLMapView.userLocation` is that the user's location typically isn't available yet in `viewDidLoad`. Use the [`mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.5.0/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:) delegate method to be notified when the user's location becomes available and when it updates.

Answer (score 8):

There is a delegate method called `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap`. Set the center of the map to the user coordinates in this method.

```
func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MGLMapView) {
    mapView.setCenter((mapView.userLocation?.coordinate)!, animated: false)
}
```